# Term for person who conducts illegal business

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for a person who conducts illegal business? Surely it is not *illegal businessman*, but maybe that could work.

Comment: "I'm a superstitious man, and if some unlucky accident should befall him, if he should get shot in the head by a police officer, or if he should hang himself in his jail cell, or if he's struck by a bolt of lightning, then I'm going to blame some of the people in this room. And that, I do not forgive. But that aside, let me say that I swear on the souls of my grandchildren, that I will not be the one to break the peace that we have made here today." - Don Corleone, The Godfather

Comment: There are very specific words, as many have mentioned, for specific crimes. Can you specify the illegal business?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be in any case a *criminal*, maybe a [*career criminal*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/career_criminal). When it goes to drug business, you call it a *druglord*, which in himself is a kind of *kingpin*. You can choose your poison.

But in the end, without contest, the word which would best fit your definition is a [*racketeer*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/racketeer), although *career criminal* or *illegal businessman* are not bad themselves.

Comment: Let's not forget _loanshark_,  _blackmailer_, _trafficker_, _gangster_, _pimp_, _conman_, etc.

Comment: grifter, smuggler, hitman, burglar, rapist, murderer, bookie,...

Comment: @Sam: the occupation of burglars, rapists and murderers doesn't strikes me as what we commonly call business

Comment: I agree that it would be uncommon, but not out of the question. A hitman, for instance _is_ a professional murderer. I suppose the difference is the motive. If it's profit, wouldn't it qualify as business?

Comment: @Sam, you may have noticed that I didn't question the fact that the hitman was doing _"business"_, I was only talking about burglars, rapists and murderers amongst the list of name you gave.

Comment: All three could be a business. Certainly burglars. Professional burglars, cat burglars, for instance, hired by other for their particular skill. On rape squads and murder squads, those doing the raping and murdering aren't doing it (solely at least) for their own pleasure or benefit. They are doing it for the advancement of their larger organization.  I separate murderer from hitman, as hitman implies a specific target, while murderer might be just an indiscriminate tool of terror.

Comment: @Sam: the key word here is _could_. In the contrary of the other in your list, the three I cited doesn't always do it for business. But I think that we are slowly arguing the semantic more than anything else. :)

Comment: Fair enough. I concede.

Answer (score 5):

I think `crook` suggests the idea of illegal business better than `criminal`; a criminal is anyone who commits/is convicted of committing a crime, which is too broad IMHO.

Depending on the illegal business in question, there may be more contextual suggestions...

Comment: I still think that racketeer hits the mark better than crook when no context are given. For me, crook doesn't mean necessary illegal business.

Answer (score 2):

> [A white-collar criminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-collar_crime)

is someone who commits crimes involving business activities, mostly desk-work crimes like accounting or insurance fraud.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "to do illegal business" means "to be in control of a criminal organization", it's *crime boss* or *crime lord*.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to use the general sense (not just of liquor) of [bootlegger](http://www.wordnik.com/words/bootlegger). See the definition for [bootleg](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bootlegger):

> to produce, reproduce, or distribute illicitly or without authorization